# How do I avoid multiple chain calls?

Tags: ruby

Imagine code that reads from a file, cleans the data and finally writes the cleaned data to a new file.

Let's briefly define these methods as Ruby stubs:

```
def write(filename, data)
   File.open(filename, "w") do |f|
      f.write(data.to_yaml)
   end
end

def read(filename)
   YAML.load_file(filename)
end

def clean(data)
   data.map do |line|
      line.strip!
   end
end
```

We can also have an orchestrator method that triggers the whole logic:

```
def read_clean_write(filename)
    write(filename, clean(read(filename)))
end
```

I think that while the isolated read, write and clean methods are modular and apply the single responsibility principle, read_clean_write is quite the opposite (and looks ugly). What is the best way to do that while keeping SRP?

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: @MathiasEttinger there you go. This is working code to be improved.  I strongly believe that the reviewer shouldn't be bothered with irrelevant implementation details though as I am asking something very specific. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine and preferable imo to the accepted answer.  The only thing I'd change is to rename `read_clean_write` to `cleanup!` or `prettify!` or something similar.   Orchestration methods are fine, and don't violate SRP, but naming them by their individual actions is not fine: the whole reason they exist is because you've identified a sequence of actions that you think of as a whole.  Figure out what that "whole" thing is and name that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to wrap it in an object with each method returning `self` so that methods can be chained.

```
class DataObject
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end

  def clean
     @data = @data.data.map(&::strip)
     self
  end

  def write(filename)
    File.open(filename, "w") do |f|
      f.write(@data.to_yaml)
    end
    self
  end

end

def read(filename)
  data = YAML.load_file(filename)
  DataObject.new(data)
end
```

Another way would be to use mixins.

```
module DataMethods

  def clean
    # need to use the destructive methods to modify self
    map!(&::strip)
    # or each(&:strip!)
    self
  end

  def write(filename)
    File.write(filename, to_yaml)
    self
  end

end

def read(filename)
  YAML.load_file(filename).extend(DataMethods)
end
```